# Querying a HP printer using RESTSharp over USB

Tags: c#, rest, usb, restsharp

I need to query a HP printer using REST(Sharp) over USB.  Windows application.

My C# applications works great using an IP address.  Now I want to do the same thing but use a USB port.  I don't know how to format the connection string

This is the code that connects nicely to the printer over the network:

```
var client = new RestClient(@"http://204.145.155.155");

var request = new RestRequest(@"/OemsiMediapath/OemsiMediapathDyn.xml",       Method.GET);

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

I am stuck with what string to supply the the RestClient constructor for a usb port.   For example, the printer is on USB002.  I have unsuccessfully tried:

```
var client = new RestClient(@"http://USB002");
```

and

```
 var client = new RestClient(@"USB002");
```

I have googled a lot on this and discovered that I am one of the VERY FEW people using REST in this sort of applications :(

Comment: Perfect, thanks for editing!  Welcome to Stack Overflow, by the way!